# Defining from another xml file

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am creating an application that uses a navigation drawer. However, the navigation drawer layout or design that I am using is from a different XML file, not on my MainActivity. I have an image in the layout that I am using that I want to apply as SetOnClickListener on my MainActivity. But I have no idea how I can define the image that is in a separate XML file in my MainActivity.

Comment: This is not a code writing service you need to show us what you've tried

Comment: Please follow these guidelines when adding your source code [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

in your case you have 2 different XML file(layout files)

1. main Activity
2. navigation drawer

each layout file must have an own java class to get access to view objects.

but if you don't have another java class for navigation drawer, use an LayoutInflater to inflate the XML layout to an view, then you can access an set the Listener to any of views you want

in main activity add:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View rootView = li.inflate(R.layout.my_navigation_drawer_layout,null,false);
```

note* replace your layout file name with my_navigation_drawer_layout

now you can declare an image view and use findViewById from rootView we create earlier

```
final ImageView img = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myImageViewName)
```

now you can set listener to img :

```
img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // write your code here!!!
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do, is easy using `<include>` tag over the XML of the MainActivity class

```
<include 
 android:layout = "YOUR LAYOUT OF THE NAVIGATION"/>
```